# How can I adjust my child element to be placed inside the parent?

Tags: html, css

How can I change the width in a child to put it inside the parent *div*?

It should be internal to padding. In this case, top and left are fine but right is not proper.

https://jsbin.com/tuhohuvoxa/edit?html,css,output

```css
.parent {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 0.1em solid;
  height: 200px;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  border: 0.1em solid;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason the child has to be `postion:absolute`? If you remove that from the .child class then it's width will automatically match the parent.

Comment: If you apply `position: absolute` on an element without a parent it's being positioned relative to, it will go out of the document flow. If you apply `position: relative` to its parent, it will be positioned absolute in the parent elements content box.

Comment: I think I;m not understanding working of absolute position. I've created one more question, if you guys can answer that will be helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76273409/why-absolute-position-respects-parents-padding-if-its-static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need the child to be absolute, simply removing the `position:absolute` from the `.child` class will make the width match the parent without overflow.

If you really need the `.child` class to be absolute you can update the `.child` and `.parent` classes as follows:

```css
.parent {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 0.1em solid;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    border: 0.1em solid;
    height: 10px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Setting `position:relative` on the parent will ensure the child is relative to the parent. Setting `left` and `right` to 0 will ensure the child matches the parent width, and adding the `margin-left` and `margin-right` will ensure the child is inset from the parent.

Comment: Yaa, I want the child to be absolute. Values for margin-left and margin-right has been provided based on the padding in the parent element. What if I don't know the padding value of parent ? How can I solve then ?

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .parent {
        border: 0.1em solid;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .child {
        position: absolute;
        border: 0.1em solid;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<div class='parent'></div>
<div class='child'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this position to your parent and child element:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  left: 0;
}
```

Then the child with position absolute will adapt to the parent.